# Divergence Theorem Question. Help Please!

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let D be the Region :

$x^2+y^2+z^2<= 4a^2$

$x^2+y^2>=a^2$

The Surface of D consists of a cylindrical part and a Spherical Part.

$F = (x+yz, y-xz, z-sin(y)e^x) $

Evaluate the Flux out of D through -

a) The whole Surface

b) The Cylindrical Part

c) The Spherical Part

Kinda lost in general about how to approach this.

Comment: Notice that $ \ \nabla  \cdot  \mathbf{F} \ = \ 3 \ $ . The volume is the portion inside a sphere of radius $ \ 2a \ $ but outside a cylinder of radius $ \ a \ $ within the sphere.

Comment: I got that part. I assume the Flux for the whole surface would be a standard double integral with $$z= 6\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}r              $$  $$a<r<2a$$  $$0<theta<2pi$$ I'm stuck in part b and c though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The geometrical object described by the inequalities is the volume interior to a sphere of radius $ \ 2a \ $ and outside of a cylinder of radius $ \ a \ $ with its symmetry axis passing through the sphere's center (the symmetry axis is along the $ \ z-$ axis, though this is actually irrelevant).

The Divergence Theorem tells us that the net flux through the surface(s) of this volume can be found by integrating the divergence of the vector field over the volume of the object.  For this field, however, the appropriate partial derivative of one term in each component is zero, so the result reduces to $ \ \nabla \ \cdot \ \mathbf{F} \ = \ 3 \ $ .

A cross-section of the volume (shaded in blue) taken along the cylinder's symmetry axis looks like this:

[image]

The height of the cylindrical section is given by $ \ \sqrt{4a^2 \ - \ a^2} \ = a \ \sqrt{3} \ $ .  The spherical portion of the volume is then missing two spherical segments or "caps" of height $ \ 2a \ - \ a \sqrt{3} \ $ ; there is a geometric formula for the volume of such a "cap".

The flux through the spherical surface is then 3 times the volume of the sphere minus the two caps.  The flux through the cylindrical "wall" is 3 times the volume of the cylinder of radius $ \ a \ $ and height $ \ a \sqrt{3} \ $ .  The flux through the entire surface, which is the surface of the blue-shaded volume (the "hollowed-out" sphere) would be 3 times the difference of these volumes.